# While Modification in a Bakery Algorithm

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, multiprocessing

Here is the Bakery Algorithm that's implementing a lock, straight from the "Herlihy The art of multiprocessor programming" book:

```
public class Bakery implements Lock {
boolean[] flag;
Label[] label;
public Bakery (int n){
    flag = new boolean[n];
    label = new Label[n];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        flag[i] = false;
        label[i] = 0;
    }
}
public void lock(){
    int i = ThreadID.get();
    flag[i] = true;
    label[i] = max(label[0],..., label[n-1]) + 1;
    while((∃k!=i)(flag[k] && (label[k], k)<<(label[i], i))){};
    }
public void unlock(){
    flag[ThreadID.get()]=false;
    }
}
```

As you may notice in the lock method, the while kind of makes sense but not totally clear. So I'm revising that part starting from the line before that:

```
label[i] = max(label[0],..., label[n-1]) + 1;
while((∃k!=i)(flag[k] && (label[k], k)<<(label[i], i))){};
```

Here's my version so far, but I'm not sure if it's correct though:

```
public void lock(){
        int i = ThreadID.get();
        flag[i] = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
            if (j != i)
                while (!(label[j] == 0 || label[i] < label[j] || 
                (flag[i] == flag[j] && i < j))) 
                }
```

Could anyone point out where I'm making the error, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the synchronization part?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik where exactly do you mean? The above piece is straight from the book and the below part, I'm editing the only 2 lines of the original algorithm.

Comment: They are using atomic boolean but yours seems as an ordinary boolean.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik you're right! I missed that part. What about now?

Comment: Did it change anything?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I guess not!